# How to track page views or analytics on partials for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, analytics, partial-views

How do people track page views or analytics for partials in Ruby on Rails? For instance, we have a form rendered in a partial, but we would like to track and analyze user behavior relating to the form.

We use Google Analytics. As far as we know, we're not supposed to embed Google Analytics code in the partial view, or it compromises the data.

We started using Mixpanel, but it begins charging after 25,000 data points. We're looking for a free solution to what should be a pretty basic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google analytics event tracking.  you can define a event for each partial and they will track them fine without messing with the automatic page tracking.

[google code link for events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)

personally I found mixpanel rather lacking and expensive when I tried it for work.

Comment: Thanks! One question: did you add the code in the head section or at the end of the page? Also, I noticed there is no "wait for Google Analytics to load" function like many other asynch libraries (e.g., Facebook). I noticed Google uses an array as the object tracker. Is this how Google ensure events are captured even when my code invokes the tracking object before the GA library is loaded?